# Installing openpose on Colab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, openpose

I have been trying to install openpose on google colab using the following script.

```
import os
from os.path import exists, join, basename, splitext

git_repo_url = 'https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose.git'
project_name = splitext(basename(git_repo_url))[0]
if not exists(project_name):
  # see: https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose/issues/949
  # install new CMake becaue of CUDA10
  !wget -q https://cmake.org/files/v3.13/cmake-3.13.0-Linux-x86_64.tar.gz
  !tar xfz cmake-3.13.0-Linux-x86_64.tar.gz --strip-components=1 -C /usr/local
  # clone openpose
  !git clone -q --depth 1 $git_repo_url
  !sed -i 's/execute_process(COMMAND git checkout master WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}\/3rdparty\/caffe)/execute_process(COMMAND git checkout f019d0dfe86f49d1140961f8c7dec22130c83154 WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}\/3rdparty\/caffe)/g' openpose/CMakeLists.txt
  # install system dependencies
  !apt-get -qq install -y libatlas-base-dev libprotobuf-dev libleveldb-dev libsnappy-dev libhdf5-serial-dev protobuf-compiler libgflags-dev libgoogle-glog-dev liblmdb-dev opencl-headers ocl-icd-opencl-dev libviennacl-dev
  # install python dependencies
  !pip install -q youtube-dl
  # build openpose
  !cd openpose && rm -rf build || true && mkdir build && cd build && cmake .. && make -j`nproc`
```

Here is a link to that colab notebook [Link to colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tugstugi/dl-colab-notebooks/blob/master/notebooks/OpenPose.ipynb#scrollTo=FOdkDhb6ga6N) . Worked fine there. However, when I try the same script on my own colab notebook I get the following error.

```
[ 82%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/util/io.cpp.o
[ 82%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/util/math_functions.cpp.o
[ 83%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/util/signal_handler.cpp.o
[ 83%] Building CXX object src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/util/upgrade_proto.cpp.o
[ 84%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libcaffe.so
CMake Error: failed to create symbolic link '../../lib/libcaffe.so': operation not supported on socket
CMake Error: cmake_symlink_library: System Error: Operation not supported
src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/build.make:2215: recipe for target 'lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0' failed
make[5]: *** [lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0] Error 1
make[5]: *** Deleting file 'lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0'
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:240: recipe for target 'src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/all' failed
make[4]: *** [src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:129: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[3]: *** [all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/openpose_lib.dir/build.make:110: recipe for target 'caffe/src/openpose_lib-stamp/openpose_lib-build' failed
make[2]: *** [caffe/src/openpose_lib-stamp/openpose_lib-build] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:72: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/openpose_lib.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/openpose_lib.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Don't know why I get this error.

```
CMake Error: failed to create symbolic link '../../lib/libcaffe.so':       operation not supported on socket
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For anyone looking of OpenPose Colab notebook: Here it is, https://colab.research.google.com/github/tugstugi/dl-colab-notebooks/blob/master/notebooks/OpenPose.ipynb#scrollTo=FOdkDhb6ga6N

Answer (score 0):

There is probably some version issue of cmake, CUDA and cuDNN. Check for compatibility.

Comment: Take a look again at [answer]. This is more of a general suggestion—it's always a good idea to check version compatibility—than an answer to this specific question